# How to make Python obj loading more efficient

Tags: python, optimization, model, 3d, loading

The loading of model files takes quite some time by using the following code:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as model_file:
    triangles = []
    vertices = []
    texcoords = []
    normals = []
    use_normals = 1
    for line in model_file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) == 0 or line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        data = line.split(" ")
        if data[0] == "v":
            vertices.append(map(float, data[1:4]))
        if data[0] == "vt":
            texcoords.append(map(float, data[1:3]))
        if data[0] == 'vn':
            normalv = map(float, data[1:4])
            normalv = normalv[0], normalv[2], normalv[1]
            normals.append(normalv)
            use_normals = 1
        if data[0] == "f":
            texture1 = 0
            texture2 = 0
            texture3 = 0
            normal1 = 0
            normal2 = 0
            normal3 = 0
            vertex1 = vertices[int(data[1].split("/")[0]) - 1]
            vertex2 = vertices[int(data[2].split("/")[0]) - 1]
            vertex3 = vertices[int(data[3].split("/")[0]) - 1]
            if len(data[1].split('/')) >= 2 and len(data[1].split('/')[1]) > 0:
                texture1 = texcoords[int(data[1].split("/")[1]) - 1]
                texture2 = texcoords[int(data[2].split("/")[1]) - 1]
                texture3 = texcoords[int(data[3].split("/")[1]) - 1]
            if len(data[1].split('/')) >= 3 and len(data[1].split('/')[1]) > 0 and len(data[1].split('/')[2]) > 0:
                normal1 = normals[int(data[1].split("/")[2]) - 1]
                normal2 = normals[int(data[2].split("/")[2]) - 1]
                normal3 = normals[int(data[3].split("/")[2]) - 1]
            triangles.append((vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, texture1, texture2, texture3, normal1, normal2, normal3))

gl_list = glGenLists(1)
glNewList(gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
i = 0
use_normals = 0
for triangle in triangles:
    if use_normals:
        glNormal3f(triangle[6][0], triangle[6][1], triangle[6][2])
    glTexCoord2f(triangle[3][0], triangle[3][1])
    glVertex3f(triangle[0][0], triangle[0][1], triangle[0][2])
    if use_normals:
        glNormal3f(triangle[7][0], triangle[7][1], triangle[7][2])
    glTexCoord2f(triangle[4][0], triangle[4][1])
    glVertex3f(triangle[1][0], triangle[1][1], triangle[1][2])
    if use_normals:
        glNormal3f(triangle[8][0], triangle[8][1], triangle[8][2])
    glTexCoord2f(triangle[5][0], triangle[5][1])
    glVertex3f(triangle[2][0], triangle[2][1], triangle[2][2])
    i += 1
glEnd()
glEndList()
return gl_list
```

How can this code be optimized? I ran cProfile and pstats to get the hardest codes:

```
41558    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
15389    0.006    0.000    0.008    0.000 error.py:206(glCheckError)
 3087    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {map}
    7    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.001 baseplatform.py:400(__call__)
15385    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 error.py:203(nullGetError)
    1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {method 'readlines' of 'file' objects}
 5664    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
18477    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {len}
 5657    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
 5651    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

It looks like the codes for the splitting, stripping and the arrays take most time, but how can I replace that codes with more efficient ones?

Comment: i think this type of question are to be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you repeating all those call to `split`? In the `data[0] == 'f'` branch try to do: `parts_one = data[1].split('/'); parts_two = data[2].split('/'); parts_three = data[3].split('/')` and then change all the various `int(data[1].split('/')[2])` to `int(parts_one[2])` etc.